# Why do data frame columns in R that I specify as numeric change to character?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I initialize a data frame in R with the following code:

```
pcts <- data.frame(group=character(),
           bonus.type=character(),
           success.rate=double(),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I then add rows to the data frame with:

```
pcts[nrow(pcts)+1,] <- c(paste(varname,gname,sep="="), btype, pct)
```

However, when I return pcts from the function, the success.rate column is character-valued. To use a value from this column in a mathematical operation, I need to use the as.double or as.numeric function. Any changes I could make to the code so this does not happen?

Comment: `c(paste(varname,gname,sep="="), btype, pct)` is a character vector because `paste(varname,gname,sep="=")` returns a character. I'd recommend constructing the data.frame upfront with the number of rows set up and the using `list` rather than `c` to fill in values.  Something like `pcts <- data.frame(group=character(500), bonus.type=character(500), success.rate=numeric(500), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and then `pcts[nrow(pcts)+1,] <- list(paste(varname,gname,sep="="), btype, pct)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the right-hand side of your command alone without assigning it to `pcts`.

This is where the coercion happens -- `c` creates an atomic vector, which can only have one type (here, everything is forced as `character`).

You should pass a `list` instead (the most basic object in R for handling multiple types), or better yet, use `rbind`:

```
pcts = rbind(pcts, data.frame(group = paste(varname,gname,sep="="), 
                              bonus.type = btype, 
                              success.rate = pct))
```

Comment: @M.Riebel c(paste(varname,gname,sep="="), btype, pct)